# Linking erros xerces-c on GNAT

Tags: c++, ada, xerces, gnat

I have to use a C++ library that uses xerces-c. Then I have an Ada project that imports two symbols from the previously mentioned C++ library. When I try to build the main of the Ada project, a bunch of undefined references arises, so I suppose I'm not linking correctly to xerces-c.
I've ensured y have the libxerces-c.a and the headers in my path (I'm using CentOS).

This is the package Linker I'm using in my gpr, which I found by googling post of people having similar link errors:

```
package Linker is
  for Linker_Options use ("-Wl", "-Bstatic", "-lxerces-c", "-Wl", "-Bdynamic");
end Linker;
```

This is an example of one of the linking erros: `` undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize(char const*, char const*, xercesc_3_2::PanicHandler*, xercesc_3_2::MemoryManager*)' ``

I'm solving the problems for now by creating a gpr library project for xerces-c with `for Externally_Built use "True";` and placing the libxerces-c.a manually in the lib directory of that project, but it really sounds weird to me. This way the linking erros disappear and everything seems to work.

Has anybody faced similar problems?

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Is your c++ library a static library? If it is then linking it to xerces won't help, you need to link to xerces in whatever is using your c++ library

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'll add an example, sorry. The C++ library is a static one, I've included the package Linker to the gpr that geneates an executable, because Linker packages are ignored in library projects.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Simon's answer solved my problem so I won't add the example, but thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to mention the `.a` library directly:

```
package Linker is
   for Switches ("ada") use ("/where/ever/libxerxes-c.a");
end Linker;
```

(a default Ada link calls in `libgnat.a` like this).

Some linkers need to see the callers of a static library before they see the library; you can use `-Wl,-v` to see what the arguments actually passed to the linker are. Your scheme of putting the xerxes-c library in an externally-built GPR may well affect the order of linker arguments.

Comment: Oh my God Simon, thank you so much. I would have never realized to do this because I had it on my path